# Main Class Cannot be found while creating a Jar File

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I'm currently running a program in eclipse (It works perfectly).

It contains two classes 
serverFrame.java
usernameCreationServer.java

in the package: accountCreationServer

I created a file on my desktop with the files above
I used terminal and CD
I created a mainfest with Main-class: accountCreationServer.serverFrame
I Javac *.java 
I used the typical cvfm command to create the jar. It does create, but it doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just export as a runnable jar in Eclipse?

Comment: Good point. I did that and it works, however it grabs my other packages from the project. Also it works on my Mac, but not on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

when creating a jar, specify the manifest with the `-m` parameter

Comment: Please clarify. I do input mainfest.txt whe compiling using cvfm.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your JAR will behave the same way as your run configuration in Eclipse, follow those steps to create it :

- menu File / Export : choose **Java/Runnable JAR** file then Next
- Choose your working launch configuration
- Browse your destination
- In Library handling, choose **"Package required libraries into generated JAR"**
- *(Optional : tick "Save as ant script", you'll get in that script hint to perform your own compilation "by hand")*
- Click Finish

File will be exported and will be runnable in any terminal by the following : 
java -jar myJarFile.jar.

More details [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm).

*(If it does not help as expected, give us more details : do you get an error message ?)*

Comment: Thank you for the response. Doing it like that works perfectly, however, it does not run on my PC.